# Are these Poisson-related problems and are the solutions correct?

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

> In a city there are three kinds of subway lines: the red, green and orange lines. Subways on each line arrive at a station according to three independent Poisson processes. On average, there is one red train every 10 minutes, one green train every 15 minutes, and one orange train every 20 minutes.
>
> (a)  When you arrive at the station what is the probability that the 1st subway that arrives is for the green line?
>
> (b)  How long will you wait, on average, before some train arrives?
>
> (c)  You have been waiting 20 minutes for a red train and have watched three orange trains to go by. What is the expected additional time you will wait for your subway?

Are these Poisson-related problems?

**Solution:**

(a) $\frac{\frac{1}{15}}{ \frac{1}{10} + \frac{1}{15} + \frac{1}{20} } = \frac{4}{13}$

(b) $\frac{1}{ \frac{1}{10} + \frac{1}{15} + \frac{1}{20} } = \frac{60}{13}$

(c) $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{10}} = 10$

Are these correct solutions as I don't see any Poisson here?

Comment: I think these are correct. You are definitely using properties of Poisson processes... what is your confusion regarding "I don't see any Poisson here"?

Comment: @angryavian, there are no Poisson formula used here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, these are Poisson processes; and the solutions are correct. The key thing to note is that summing independent Poisson processes gives a Poisson process. Thinking of Poisson processes as arrivals, this says that if you count arrivals from two independent Poisson processes, then you get a Poisson process. You can read more about Poisson processes in [Section 1.4](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~ps422/) of Perla Sousi's lecture notes.

The main result being used here is that interarrival times in a Poisson process are exponentially distributed, and hence have the memoryless property.

(a/b) The time to get a red is exponential with rate $\lambda_r = 1/10$, green with rate $\lambda_g = 1/15$ and orange with rate $\lambda_o = 1/20$; call these arrival times $E_r$, $E_g$ and $E_o$. The first arrival is then $\min\{E_r,E_g,E_o\}$, and minimum of exponentials is exponential with parameter $\lambda := \lambda_r+\lambda_g+\lambda_o$; the expected time is then $1/\lambda$.

For (a), you can just calculate directly $\Pr( \text{Exponential}(\lambda_g) < \text{Exponential}(\lambda_r+\lambda_o) )$.

You can also see this as a sort of symmetry argument. Suppose we're trying to calculate $\Pr( E_1 = \text{Exponential}(1) < E_2 = \text{Exponential}(2)$. Write $\text{Exponential}(2)$ as $\min\{E_{2,1} = \text{Exponential}(1),E_{2,1}' = \text{Exponential}(1)\}$. There are then three exponentials ($E_1$, $E_{2,1}$ and $E_{2,1}'$) each of rate 1; if the first is the smallest, then $E_1 < E_2$, while otherwise $E_2 > E_1$. In this set-up, clearly $\Pr(E_1 < E_2) = 1/3$, by symmetry.

For (c), just use the memoryless property and the fact that the Poisson processes are independent, so it doesn't matter that you've seen orange buses